# Chance of rolling highest after removing highest and lowest?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

**The problem:**
Say two people each roll 3 20-sided dice (a total of 6 dice).
Person 1, only keeps the lowest die from the throw.
Person 2, only keeps the highest die from the throw.
What is the chance that person 1 rolls higher (not equal) than person 2?

Furthermore: I am going to check what happens to the percentage if they roll 4,5,6 dice instead of 3.

**Solution:**
Obviously I am interested in all the help I can get. I would like a solution/approach that can be used with different amounts of rolls, and give an answer, preferable something like change x for amount of dice in each roll. 
I don't study math in university.

**My attempts:**
I have tried to calculate it in Excel, but my math/excel skills were not great enough for me to get beyond a scenario where person 1 rolls 2 dice, and keeps the lowest and checks if it is higher than person 2, without removing the highest. 
I check before posting if I could find the answer in this site.

Comment: It seems to me that the following approach should work.  For the moment, forget about who's rolling which die.  Just take $6~20-$sided dice and roll them.  What is the probability that there is a tie for the median roll?  Assuming that hasn't happened, determine the probability (which will be $1/20$) that the three highest rolls belonged to the first player.

Comment: Thank you! (: @RobertShore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RobertShore's Comment may lead you to an analytic solution. Meanwhile,
it is easy to get an approximate answer by simulation.

In R statistical software, `sample(1:20, 3, rep=T)` simulates three rolls of a 20-sided die. So the following
program finds the proportion of plays out of a million
in which the first player wins. For the parameters you specify,
the answer is $0.043 \pm 0.0004.$ (If each person rolls 6 dice,
the probability drops to about $0.0008.)$

```
set.seed(406)    # for reproducibility (omit this line for fresh simulation)
m = 10^6;  f = 20;  r = 3
w1 = replicate( m, min(sample(1:f,r,rep=T)) > max(sample(1:f,r,rep=T)) )
mean(w1)  
[1] 0.04303
2*sd(w1)/sqrt(m)
[1] 0.0004058675
```

*Notes:* You can install R to run under most operating systems with a
free download from `www.r-project.org`. On my ageing computer the simulation takes less than 15 sec.